# View all applied configurations of an object

Tags: kubernetes, apply, configuration-files, kubectl, revision-history

The command:

```
kubectl apply view-last-applied -f object.yml
```

displays the *latest* applied configuration file of an object.

Does a command exist that gives the *entire* 'applied' history of a given object?

For example, given the created configuration (using `kubectl create -f pod.spec --save-config`):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-pod
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.7.9
```

and the applied configurations (using `kubectl apply -f pod.spec`):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-pod
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.9
```

revision 2:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-pod
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.9.1
```

the command should give:

```
$ kubectl appy log -f pod.spec

applied <later date>:

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-pod
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.9.1


applied <earlier date>:

apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-pod
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.9
```

Answer (score 0):

No, only the latest applied configuration is persisted in the object

Comment: Could you please point me to documentation or a repo. file (line) that shows this?

Comment: The configuration is persisted as an annotation on the object. If you fetch it and output the objects as yaml (`kubectl get -f object.yml -o yaml`) you can see the annotations